# Disable the Reveal Password feature in the MS Edge Browser using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am aware that using GPO we are able to disable the reveal password feature using the below option:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Credential User Interface
"Do not display the password reveal button" Select "Enabled" option.

I want to know if anyone has managed to do this using python.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you can try to use python to add the corresponding registry key to achieve this requirement. It actually achieves the same effect as setting a group policy.

You could refer to [Windows registry access](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/winreg.html), and add the registry key `PasswordRevealEnabled` under this path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`.When the [PasswordRevealEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#passwordrevealenabled) value is set to 1, it is enabled, and 0 is disabled. Also note that this policy only affects the browser password reveal button, it doesn't affect websites' custom reveal buttons.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.